# lateinit property movieAdapter has not been initialized Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, adapter

How can I resolve the error? lateinit property movieAdapter has not been initialized. I don't understand how to initiate this

```
class SearchActivity : BaseAppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var movieViewModel: MovieViewModel
    private lateinit var movieAdapter: MovieAdapter
    private lateinit var tvShowAdapter: TvShowAdapter
    private lateinit var query: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search)

        query = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_QUERY)!!
        movieViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MovieViewModel::class.java)
        movieViewModel.movies.observe(this, getMovie)
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(
            applicationContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            resources.getStringArray(R.array.filter_search)
        )
        spinner_search_activity.adapter = adapter
        spinner_search_activity.onItemSelectedListener =
            object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

                }

                override fun onItemSelected(
                    parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                    view: View?,
                    position: Int,
                    id: Long
                ) {
                    pb_search_activity.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    tv_null_search_activity.visibility = View.GONE
                    if (spinner_search_activity.selectedItemPosition == 0) {
                        searchMovie()
                    } else if (spinner_search_activity.selectedItemPosition == 1) {
                        searchTvShow()
                    }
                }

            }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

`movieAdapter = MovieAdapter(/*pass the required data to construct this*/)`

Where to initiate this ? , it depends on the items required by the constructor.

Comment: how can I filll it, if the second constructor is list? I confuse to fill it,
example,
movieAdapter = MovieAdapter( this, "list")
thank you

Comment: If you have a Movie class , you got to create a list of Movies and pass it to the Movie Adapter.